# Why can't I see any markers on google maps react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, marker

I have been building the front end of an application that has the google maps API enabled. I want to have the user click on the map to add markers, and store it into an array; However after I implemented an add marker function to the onClick of the google map tag... The markers won't render.

I have had a lot of difficulty implementing the add marker function in react, and watched several tutorials but cannot seem to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    const options = {
        styles: mapStyles,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
    }

    var markersArray = [];
    function addMarker(event){
            let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            time: new Date(),
            draggable: true
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);
    }


    const Map = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(props =>
        <GoogleMap
          defaultZoom={8}
          defaultCenter={{ lat: this.state.mapPosition.lat, lng: this.state.mapPosition.lng }}
          options={options}
          onClick={(event) => {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(markersArray);
            addMarker(event);
        }}
        >

        {markersArray.map((marker) =>(
            <Marker
                key={marker.time.toISOString()}
                position={{lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
            />
        ))}

        <AutoComplete
            style={{width: "100%", height:'40px'}}
            types={['(regions)']}
            onPlaceSelected={this.onPlaceSelected}
        />

        </GoogleMap>
      ));
```

I believe the issue is with this but i'm not sure how to make it work.

```
        {markersArray.map((marker) =>(
            <Marker
                key={marker.time.toISOString()}
                position={{lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
            />
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`markersArray` is a plain array. When you do `addMarker(event);` you're not updating the state of your component, it's just a plain array. So probably React is not aware of that change. If you're using hooks, you could create a state with your markers like this

```
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([])
```

use that `markers` array to render the `<Marker />` and then on your event to add the marker

```
onClick={(event) => {
  setMarker(previousMarkers => previousMarkers.concat([event]))
}
```

this will cause a re-render with the new value of `markers` and you should be able to see them.

If it's not a functional component and it's classes, it's the same, but you would define the markers in your class' state

```
constructor(props) { 
  super(props)
  this.state = { markers: [] }
  this.addMarker = this.addMarker.bind(this)

}

// function class below
addMarker(marker) {
  this.setState(previousState => previousState.concat([marker])
}
```

and in your event, you'd call `this.addMarker(marker)`